# Application icon does not appear after installing android app

Tags: android, application-icon

I am developing an android app and when I install the app on android phone, the application icon does not appears in application section. But it appears in application manager and I can make uninstallation. After googling, some said I need to rebuild my project and to make sure the app icon in drawable resource. I already tried for this solution and the problem is still occurring. The manifest file I created is as follow:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.view" />
            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You know, it happened with me as well.. when I restarted my phone it worked. Strange. But yes, rebuilding should definitely work. That's the logical step.

Comment: Thank you Pramod. Now, I have passed the problem by removing <data android:scheme="geo"/>. But, I want to know when this data tag need and why it's still working even I removed it? Please let me know in detail about this data tag. Actually, I'm a beginner in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe geo scheme cannot be used with Launcher. I can't find any documentation but in [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) tutorial they suggest to use with default category.

Please try to move your location related code to another activity and move scheme=geo filter to that one.

Comment: Thank you kozaxinam. I have passed the problem by removing <data android:scheme="geo"/>. Please let me know when this data tag need.

Comment: I think it is propper to separate into a different intent filter. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33097868/7270736.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest in activity try using or add another intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Change

`android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

With your icon

if you wanna to remove this icon you have to remove from all folder like

```
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
```

Comment: Thanks Anik Islam Abhi. I have solved the problem. I removed <data android:scheme="geo"/> and it's working now. But, please let me know when this data tag need.

Answer (score 0):

I set `action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` two of mine activity intent.For this I'm having two launcher icon.When I noticed that I remove one activity's intent filter,but My launcher icon disappear.I tried all the mentioned above solution but didn't work.As I noticed `Darpan's` comment about re-starting your phone will fix it I tried and It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my manifest included a label for the main activity. I deleted the label, restarted the app and the icon magically appeared in the applications list.[image]