# My application icon doesn't appear when I debug or Run 'app' on android studio, what happened?

Tags: android, apk, appicon

My application icon no longer appears on my android phone screen when I debug like it used to. I know this has something to do with the androidmanifest.xml file. I've looked up several solutions for me but those solutions resulted in my application being unable to even run in the first place.

What could be the problem here?

I have tried the solutions mentioned here:

[Android Studio: App icon doesn't appear in the home screen or app list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097743/android-studio-app-icon-doesnt-appear-in-the-home-screen-or-app-list)

[Launcher icon missing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133954/launcher-icon-missing-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is my android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="sg.edu.singaporetech.teamproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- allow usage of camera for Android -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/> <!-- to run foreground service for steps -->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".StepsNotification"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/exersize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".DispatchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".profile.editProfile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".registration.RegisterActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".home.HomeActivity">
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".StepsBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".StepsService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i guess your icon size is too large it must b localised according to device resolutions and its size for max resolution (xxxhdpi) must not exceed `200px`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the line,
    `android:icon="@drawable/exersize"`

In the application tag, app icon must he placed in the mipmap folder as it meant for the app icon only. Mipmap must have all scales of the icon.